# Send Dataframe Using Python works in Python, Not in Spark/Databricks

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

So I have this code that works perfectly in Python (thanks to some help from StackOverflow) and I wanted to put it into Databricks.

In the production environment, Import_MICS will be a data frame that contains some error code that we will be sending to the users.

I get error codes making reference to encoding when I try to run it in Spark/Databricks, but I'm not sure why that would be the case.

Any help as to why python code that works in Python but not in Databricks would be much appreciated

When I try to run it with the sample data below, I get the following error:

```
    UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\ufffd' in position 8091: ordinal not in range(128)
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-11-e3342ca6d73a> in <module>()
         28 
         29 
    ---> 30 msg = MIMEText(content, text_subtype)
         31 msg['Subject']=       subject
         32 msg['From']   = sender # some SMTP servers will do this automatically, not all

    /usr/lib/python2.7/email/mime/text.pyc in __init__(self, _text, _subtype, _charset)
         28         MIMENonMultipart.__init__(self, 'text', _subtype,
         29                                   **{'charset': _charset})
    ---> 30         self.set_payload(_text, _charset)

    /usr/lib/python2.7/email/message.pyc in set_payload(self, payload, charset)
        224         self._payload = payload
        225         if charset is not None:
    --> 226             self.set_charset(charset)
        227 
        228     def set_charset(self, charset):

    /usr/lib/python2.7/email/message.pyc in set_charset(self, charset)
        260             self.set_param('charset', charset.get_output_charset())
        261         if isinstance(self._payload, unicode):
    --> 262             self._payload = self._payload.encode(charset.output_charset)
        263         if str(charset) != charset.get_output_charset():
        264             self._payload = charset.body_encode(self._payload)

    UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\ufffd' in position 8091: ordinal not in range(128)
```

When I use my own dataset, I get a similar, but slightly different message:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'encode'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-ed199c64eb83> in <module>()
     21 
     22 #msg = MIMEText(content, text_subtype)
---> 23 msg = MIMEText(content)
     24 msg['Subject']=       subject
     25 msg['From']   = sender # some SMTP servers will do this automatically, not all

/usr/lib/python2.7/email/mime/text.pyc in __init__(self, _text, _subtype, _charset)
     28         MIMENonMultipart.__init__(self, 'text', _subtype,
     29                                   **{'charset': _charset})
---> 30         self.set_payload(_text, _charset)

/usr/lib/python2.7/email/message.pyc in set_payload(self, payload, charset)
    224         self._payload = payload
    225         if charset is not None:
--> 226             self.set_charset(charset)
    227 
    228     def set_charset(self, charset):

/usr/lib/python2.7/email/message.pyc in set_charset(self, charset)
```

My code is as follows:

```
 import pandas as pd 

 Import_MICS="https://www.iso20022.org/sites/default/files/ISO10383_MIC/ISO10383_MIC.csv"
MICS=pd.read_csv(Import_MICS,encoding = 'ISO-8859-1')
SMTPserver = 'email-smtp.us-east-2.amazonaws.com'
sender =     'x.com'
destination = ['x.com']

USERNAME = "efsdff"
PASSWORD = "sfdfsf"

# typical values for text_subtype are plain, html, xml
text_subtype = 'html'


content="""\
Test message number 2
"""
content=MICS.to_html()
subject="Sent from Python"

import sys
import os
import re

from smtplib import SMTP_SSL as SMTP       # this invokes the secure SMTP protocol (port 465, uses SSL)
from email.mime.text import MIMEText


msg = MIMEText(content, text_subtype)
msg['Subject']=       subject
msg['From']   = sender # some SMTP servers will do this automatically, not all



conn = SMTP(SMTPserver)
conn.set_debuglevel(False)
conn.starttls
conn.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD)
conn.sendmail(sender, destination, msg.as_string())
```